# How to get maximum count of a field in a table in Tsql and groupby

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table `Customer_Complex_LoginLogs` to log customer entrance.

I want to get the maximum number of entrances that has occurred on a single day (and I want to know the day that this occurred).

I know I should perform a `group by TFEnteranceDate`

How can I achieve this in TSQL ?

TableName :

```
Customer_Complex_LoginLogs
```

Table fields :

```
Id guid  PK
Id_Customer guid   FK
TFEnteranceDate datetime
TFEnteranceDatep nvarchar(10)
```

Comment: @Sepster I want the maximum number of enterance in any day It has happend

Comment: @MartinSmith  I added table details

Comment: @Karamafrooz - You should also include datatypes as the answer will be different if `datetime` vs `date`. And as a general rule including info about any keys and indexes on the table is useful too.

Comment: @MartinSmith I added the info

Comment: So Steve's answer will probably work for you. You should not store dates as `nvarchar(10)` though. Use the `date` datatype if 2008+ or `datetime` if earlier

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks alot ! I store persian date as nvarchar(10) and I have another column with the type datetime to store gregorian date :)

Comment: If you are on 2008+ you could consider changing that `datetime` to `date` for the Gregorian date if you aren't storing any time part.

Comment: @MartinSmith I also store time part so I think datetime is better for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information this could be a simple GROUP BY

```
SELECT TOP 1 TFEnteranceDate, Count(TFEnteranceDate) as Enterance
FROM Customer_Complex_LoginLogs 
GROUP BY TFEnteranceDate
ORDER BY Count(TFEnteranceDate) DESC
```

EDIT: The day with the max number of TFEnteranceDate recorded

Comment: +1 Ahhh I've been working with (against?) MS Access recently (blugrh!) and completely forgot about the TOP 1/ORDER BY "pattern" to avoid having to join back to get the row associated with a max value.  Nice one.